# SSL Connection cannot be established error in Azure VM Connection via powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, ssl, virtual-machine, remote-access

Using the Get-AzureCertificate command install the certificate and executed the commands in remote azure vm from local machine from 09-01-2015 (yesterday)  onwards cannot able to execute the commands from local machine. Got the following error message when connecting to the azure vm.

> [xxxxxx.cloudapp.net] Connecting to remote server xxxxxx.cloudapp.net
>   failed with thefollowing error message : The SSL connection cannot be
>   established. Verify that the service on the remote host isproperly
>   configured to listen for HTTPS requests. Consult the logs and
>   documentation for the WS-Management servicerunning on the destination,
>   most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service,
>   run the followingcommand on the destination to analyze and configure
>   the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig -transport:https". For
>   moreinformation, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.    +
>   CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (xxxxxx.cloudapp.net:String) [],
>   PSRemotingTransportException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   -2144108102,PSSessionStateBroken

Comment: What type of VM are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft made changes to the standard image on 8/24 which caused the WinRM SSL connection with self signed certs to break.

If you use the July 26 image for Server 2012 R2 it will work.  The image name is:

a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-20150726-en.us-127GB.vhd

Comment: Very helpful. Spinning up a VM with the 7/26 image worked perfectly.

Comment: The latest version of the Server 2012 R2 image now works.  We opened a support case with Microsoft and they have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to what Mike suggested:

The july image didn't work out for me. But with the June image I could use winrm over https.

I create my server in west-europe. So maybe your region also has influence over which image you get.

Comment: Same for me in North-Europe and West, had to use the June image. Both Jul and Aug did not work.